# Erlang: Mnesia can not create schema while release with rebar

Tags: erlang, mnesia, rebar

When I call mnesia:create_schema on startup, the program crashes.
If I run my program in ebin without releasing it, it works find.
The error log as follows:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 3-Jul-2013::09:44:06 ===
application: eddy
exited: {bad_return,
         {{eddy_app,start,[normal,[]]},
          {'EXIT',
           {{badmatch,
             {error,
              {'EXIT',
               {undef,
                [{mnesia_backup,open_write,
                  ["/home/cometeor/eddy/rel/eddy/Mnesia.eddy@127.0.0.1/eddy@127.0.0.1137284464686415846847780"],
                  []},
                 {mnesia_bup,do_apply,4,
                  [{file,"mnesia_bup.erl"},{line,387}]},
                 {mnesia_bup,make_initial_backup,3,
                  [{file,"mnesia_bup.erl"},{line,378}]},
                 {mnesia_bup,create_schema,2,
                  [{file,"mnesia_bup.erl"},{line,348}]},
                 {eddy_database,start,0,
                  [{file,"src/eddy_database.erl"},{line,24}]},
                 {eddy_app,start,2,[{file,"src/eddy_app.erl"},{line,16}]},
                 {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                  [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}},
            [{eddy_database,start,0,
              [{file,"src/eddy_database.erl"},{line,24}]},
             {eddy_app,start,2,[{file,"src/eddy_app.erl"},{line,16}]},
             {application_master,start_it_old,4,
              [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Resolved.Must add

```
{app, mnesia, [{mod_cond, app}]},
```

to reltool.config.