# Erlang/OTP app using rebar returns crash dump when releasing

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, rebar

I followed the tutorial many times and, created a small app using rebar and release it successfully. But when I come to the main application (calendarApp), crash dump was returned. I made some changes but the result is the same. I would like to know what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix this.

At the end, when I do start and attach, it returns  "Node is not running!".

I will show you:

```
sonu@sonu-Ideapad-Z570:~/calendarApp/rel$ ./calendarApp/bin/calendarApp console
Exec: /home/sonu/release/calendarApp/rel/calendarApp/erts-5.10.4/bin/erlexec -boot /home/sonu/release/calendarApp/rel/calendarApp/releases/1/calendarApp -mode embedded -config /home/sonu/release/calendarApp/rel/calendarApp/releases/1/sys.config -args_file /home/sonu/release/calendarApp/rel/calendarApp/releases/1/vm.args -- console
Root: /home/sonu/release/calendarApp/rel/calendarApp
Erlang R16B03 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

{global,calendarApp_sup} (<0.216.0>) starting....
{global,calendarApp_server} (<0.217.0>) starting ......
Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
(calendarApp@127.0.0.1)1> 
=INFO REPORT==== 19-Jan-2016::09:50:45 ===
application: calendarApp
exited: {{shutdown,
{failed_to_start_child,calendarApp_server,
    {undef,
    [{mnesia,create_schema,
        [['calendarApp@127.0.0.1']],
        []},
    {calendarApp_db,init,0,
        [{file,"src/calendarApp_db.erl"},{line,7}]},
    {calendarApp_server,init,1,
        [{file,"src/calendarApp_server.erl"},{line,49}]},
    {gen_server,init_it,6,
        [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
    {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
        [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}},
{calendarApp_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
type: permanent
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"   {application_start_failure,calendarApp,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,calendarApp_server,{undef,[{mnesia,create_schema,[['calendarApp@127.0.0.1']],[]},{calendarApp_db,init,0,[{file,\"src/calendarApp_db.erl\"},{line,7}]},{calendarApp_server,init,1,[{file,\"src/calendarApp_server.erl\"},{line,49}]},{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,\"gen_server.erl\"},{line,304}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,\"proc_lib.erl\"},{line,239}]}]}}},{calendarApp_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller)   ({application_start_failure,calendarApp,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,calendarApp_server,{undef,[{mnesia,create_schema, [['calendarApp@127.0.0.1']],
sonu@sonu-Ideapad-Z570:~/calendarApp/rel$ ./calendarApp/bin/calendarApp console
```

If anyone knows the problem, please help me to fix this.

Comment: The crash dump says that the `mnesia:create_schema/1` function is undefined, because you should add it into `reltool.config` file. This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444760/erlang-mnesia-can-not-create-schema-while-release-with-rebar) is possibly a duplicate of your question and answers how to add `mnesia` application to the release.